# Interstitial iAd within SKScene in iOS Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, iad

The sample iAd code for interstitials uses the main ViewController to present the full-screen interstitial ad.

However, I would like to be able to trigger the ad from the SKScene in my iOS Sprite Kit game.

I can easily do so in the main view controller (`ViewController.m`) like so:

```
[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

However, I've tried to access the root view controller which sets up the scene in the `viewDidLoad` method of :

```
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
SKScene * scene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

In `SKScene.m` I've tried this:

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

and X-Code throws this:

```
No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'requestInterstitialAdPresentation'
```

This is probably something simple, basically I need to access the ViewController object that created the SKView and SKScene so I can send the `requestInterstitialAdPresentation` message to that object (and display the ad).

Comment: Did you try to cast the view controller like this? [(ViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController requestInterstitialAdPresentation];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you pass an instance of your view controller that implements `requestInterstitialAdPresentation` to your `SKScene` instance? That way, you can reference the VC directly rather than having to go through the window, which seems to be error-prone.

If you're going to take this advice — without knowing too much about your codebase — I would hazard a guess that it may make sense to create a delegate interface for the scene and to implement it in the view controller. The interface would look something like:

```
@protocol AdDelegate
- (BOOL)requestInterstitialAdPresentation;
@end
```

As far as understanding why your root view controller doesn't implement `requestInterstitialAdPresentation`, I suppose your best bet would be to debug the application and see what's going on. My suspicion is that you're dealing with a container view controller that wraps your main VC, or the scene you're presenting shows up in a different window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple notification to communicate back to your viewController.In your viewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(requestInterstitialAdPresentation) name:@"showAdd" object:nil];
```

Then in your scene post the notification whenever you want your ad presented.
In your SKScene:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showAdd" object:nil];
```

Hopes this helps

Comment: By far the easiest way.